# Docker logs not showing colors (express + nodejs image)

Tags: node.js, docker

A petty, yet interesting question (for me):

I'm trying to create docker image from a small server( nodejs + express) I wrote. My server code is:

```
var express = require('express');
var Inflector = require('inflected');
var colors = require('colors');

var app = express();

app.get('/hello/:name', function(req, res, next){
    var name = Inflector.titleize(req.params.name);
    console.log("Saying hello to " + name.yellow);
    res.send('Hello ' + name);
});

var port = 9090;
app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log(('App is running on port ' + port).inverse);
});
```

I'm creating my image with this Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:centos6

RUN     rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm

RUN     yum install -y npm

COPY . /src

RUN cd /src; npm install

EXPOSE 9090

CMD ["node", "/src/index.js"]
```

Building and running the image with the common commands:

```
docker build -t username:centos-nodejs
docker run -p 9090:9090 username:centos-nodejs
```

I was expecting the logs to show up with colors in the command line as they do without docker (e.g. `node index.js`).

What is the cause and can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run your container with "-it" options:

```
docker run -it -p 9090:9090 username:centos-nodejs
```

Comment: How can I do this with `docker-compose`?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150040/2921592):

Comment: Is it something doable for `docker logs`?

Answer (score 6):

Not quite the answer to this specific problem, but if you're using the debug library and have the same issue there is a non-documented environment variable that enables the colors even when in a non TTY:

https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/blob/39ecd87bcc145de5ca1cbea1bf4caed02c34d30a/node.js#L45

So adding `DEBUG_COLORS=true` to your environment variables fixes it for the debug library colors.

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a lot! Also works in `docker-compose`