# Interactive shell using Docker Compose

Tags: shell, docker, interactive, docker-compose

Is there any way to start an interactive shell in a container using Docker Compose only? I've tried something like this, in my docker-compose.yml:

```
myapp:
  image: alpine:latest
  entrypoint: /bin/sh
```

When I start this container using docker-compose up it's exited immediately. Are there any flags I can add to the `entrypoint` command, or as an additional option to `myapp`, to start an interactive shell?

I know there are native docker command options to achieve this, just curious if it's possible using only Docker Compose, too.

Comment: This is not supposed to work. For example, if you have multiple images with `/bin/sh` entrypoint in your compose file, what should it do?

Comment: Hmh, why not just start multiple shells? For example, a shell into a mysql container to work  with mysql cli, and a shell into a backup container to run backup commands?

Comment: what about `docker-compose run myapp` ?

Comment: @ibova The problem is with `docker-compose run myapp` is that it won't expose the ports. So you have to use `docker-compose run --service-ports myapp` but still its not very convenient.

Comment: `entrypoint: /bin/sh` should be `entrypoint: "/bin/sh"`

Comment: @codentary It is just YAML, so quotes are optional in this particular case.

Answer (score 791):

You need to include the following lines in your `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    image: app:1.2.3
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
```

The first corresponds to `-i` in `docker run` and the second to `-t`.

Comment: that `stdin_open` is the missing link, for simply providing me the expected behavior when I attach to one of my containers that is already running a shell.

Comment: @TheFool,
Even I got the same issue.
Its better to run `docker-compose run <service_name>`

Comment: Where exactly is this added? Inside the service?

Comment: This seems to be the best answer to the OP's question.. since the issue is that the container exits immediately otherwise, so getting a shell using `docker exec` on it is not going to work.

Comment: This gives me an error on Windows: `colorama\win32.py, line 152, in SetConsoleTitle: ctypes.ArgumentError: ‘ValueError’: embedded null character`

Comment: the only thing missing here is how to get *out* of the shell without exiting the process and stopping the container. Press CTRL-P-Q to detach.

Comment: This still does not work if I use `docker-compose up` and entrypoint `["/bin/sh"]`. Although the container does not exist immediately. Is the input attached to the entrypoint?

Comment: Same issue as @doraemon dockerfile is just FROM debian:bullseye-slim; entrypoint ["/bin/bash"]; these options prevent it from exiting immediatly, and container says it's up, but there is no input/output.  docker run -it {image} works as expected.

Comment: Works well with docker attach <container_name>

Comment: This saved my day for different issue with high CPU usage of python interpreter even being in idle, stdin_open: true helped for this problem.

Comment: Any chance to get container shell right in same docker-compose call? I mean going each time to another terminal to call docker-compose exec is a bit annoying...

Answer (score 463):

The canonical way to get an interactive shell with docker-compose is to use:

```
docker-compose run --rm myapp
```

With the service name `myapp` taken from your example.
More general: it *must* be an existing service name in your docker-compose file, `myapp` is not just a command of your choice. For example, `bash` instead of `myapp` would not work here.

You can set `stdin_open: true, tty: true`, however that won't actually give you a proper shell with `up`, because logs are being streamed from all the containers.

You can also use:

```
docker exec -ti <container name> /bin/bash
```

to get a shell on a running container.

Comment: Note you need to add `--service-ports` if you expose any ports(ie for a web server)

Comment: This creates a new container every time you run the above command. If you want a more space efficient use the approach given by @lynx0123.

Comment: I've updated my answer to provide more information and add the `--rm` flag so that the container is removed.  The answer by @lynx0123 is not correct. You will not get an interactive shell if you run `docker-compose up`.

Comment: To get this to work using Docker for Windows, I needed docker-compose v. 1.9.0 (see Github [issue](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3194) and [PR](https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/3980)). As of 12/19/16, this only ships with beta versions of Docker for Windows. Then `docker-compose run` works. You'll also want to add `command: /bin/bash` to docker-compose.yml.

Comment: This should be the top answer. This is what I was looking for when I came here.

Comment: docker-compose up -d && docker attach <container_name>

Comment: docker attach is exactly what I've been looking for to connect to my python pdb debugger, thanks! But it won't always help get a shell on the container unless there is an interactive shell running already. Containers are probably already running something more useful.

Comment: When using docker exec -ti <container name> /bin/bash, you do need the tty: true in docker-compose.yml, otherwise you receive a message that the container is not a tty

Comment: @dnephin is there a way to supply the value for '--rm' in the compose yml file?

Answer (score 146):

The official getting started example (https://docs.docker.com/compose/gettingstarted/) uses the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
```

After you start this with `docker-compose up`, you can shell into either your `redis` container or your `web` container with:

```sh
docker-compose exec redis sh
docker-compose exec web sh
```

Comment: And why with other images I can't do it, I just asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66638731/why-do-i-need-tty-true-in-docker-compose-yml-and-other-images-do-not

Comment: This works like charm! I was trying with `docker exec -it <container name> sh` and it failed once and other again. running through `docker-compose exec` really works!

Answer (score 90):

`docker-compose run myapp sh` should do the deal.

There is some confusion with `up`/`run`, but `docker-compose run` docs have great explanation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run

Comment: Thank you so much. Just a little add to clarify. docker-compose run [your-service-name-defined-in-docker-compose.yml] [sh or bash].

Comment: I think this is the most straightforward of answers. I needed to verify the environment is correct for the service by going `docker-compose run <service-name> sh` as suggested.

Comment: To override the `entrypoint` configured in `docker-compose.yml` I had to use: `docker-compose run --entrypoint /bin/bash myapp`

Comment: This really did the trick, when working with docker-compose!!

Comment: Great alternative command Instead of docker-compose up later running interactive shell from the container. I do use `docker-compose -f other-compose-file.yml run myapp sh` to run specific version of node with alpine image. where -f specifies yml file that declares myapp service.

Answer (score 65):

If anyone from the future also wanders up here:

```
docker-compose exec service_name sh
```

or

```
docker-compose exec service_name bash
```

or you can run single lines like

```
docker-compose exec service_name php -v
```

That is after you already have your containers up and running.

The `service_name` is defined in your `docker-compose.yml` file

Comment: This is incorrect it is: `docker-compose exec <service_name>`, not `docker-compose exec <container_name>`.

Comment: And why with other images I can't do it, I just asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66638731/why-do-i-need-tty-true-in-docker-compose-yml-and-other-images-do-not

Answer (score 38):

Using docker-compose, I found the easiest way to do this is to do a `docker ps -a` (after starting my containers with `docker-compose up`) and get the ID of the container I want to have an interactive shell in (let's call it xyz123).

Then it's a simple matter to execute
`docker exec -ti xyz123 /bin/bash`

and voila, an interactive shell.

Comment: Not sure why this was down-voted - it's a great way to get debugging in case anything goes wrong, and I used this method with success, like, within a minute of reading this solution.

Comment: @ericmjl Because it's a two step process where the question asked specifically about using docker-compose features, and was already stated in the other answer

Answer (score 12):

You can get an interactive shell with docker-compose using the following command (considering that the `yml` has specified a service called `myservice`):

```
$ docker-compose exec myservice sh
```

In the case of using a different `yml` file name, such as `docker-compose-mycompose.yml`, to get the interactive terminal, it is necessary to specify the `yml`, like:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-mycompose.yml exec myservice sh
```

Comment: This requires, that the container is already running. A prerequisite for that is, that *Dockerfile* has a CMD [...] line, that does not exit immediately, which seems to be the case in the question.

Answer (score 10):

This question is very interesting for me because I have problems, when I run container after execution finishes immediately exit and I fixed with -it:

```
docker run -it -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v $(pwd):/app <your_container_id>
```

And when I must automate it with docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
    frontend:
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
        ports: 
            - "3000:3000"
        volumes: 
            - /app/node_modules
            - .:/app
```

This makes the trick: **stdin_open: true, tty: true**

This is a project generated with create-react-app

Dockerfile.dev it looks this that:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR '/app'

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install

COPY . . 

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Hope this example will help other to run a frontend(react in example) into docker container.

Comment: Hey @Carnaru can you tell me the reason of using "- /app/node_modules" command under the volume section

Comment: @aashirkhan it's related to using volumes and having the container use the node_modules in the container rather than your local files

Answer (score 9):

I prefer

```sh
docker-compose exec my_container_name bash
```

Answer (score 5):

A addition to this old question, as I only had the case last time. The difference between sh and bash. So it can happen that for some bash doesn't work and only sh does.

So you can:
`docker-compose exec CONTAINER_NAME sh`

and in most cases: `docker-compose exec CONTAINER_NAME bash`

use.

If you have time. The difference between sh and bash is well explained here:
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/sh-vs-bash

Answer (score 4):

You can do `docker-compose exec SERVICE_NAME sh` on the command line. The `SERVICE_NAME` is defined in your `docker-compose.yml`. For example,

```
services:
    zookeeper:
        image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
        ports:
          - "2181:2181"
```

The `SERVICE_NAME` would be "zookeeper".

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation -> https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/

You can use this `docker-compose run --rm app bash`

[app] is the name of your service in docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the `shell` through docker `compose run`.

**compose.yml:**

```
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest
```

**Commandline on host**

```
docker compose run --rm myapp sh -c "/bin/sh"
```

You might also want to mount some volumes in the compose file to persist whatever you are doing inside the container in **compose.yml**:

```
services:
  myapp:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

I have mounted the current directory on host to the directory */app* inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following steps can open an interactive shell, although it's not directly with `docker-compose`:

- After running `docker-compose up`
- Check the name of the container using `docker ps -a`
- Choose the container name you want to open an interactive bash shell for
- Run `docker exec -it containerName bash`

Your terminal should now be in the bash shell of the container and you can interact with its content.

Hope this helps.