# docker-compose start container in interactive mode with ssh

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose

My docker-compose.yaml file is as below

```
version: '3'
services:
  client:
    image: thusithathilina/my_image
    ports:
      - "5000:22"
    command: ["/usr/sbin/sshd"]
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

But this doesn't start the container in interactive mode. I want to start the ssh at container startup with interactive mode. Could someone point what I'm doing wrong here?

Host is Linux 9a65bd45c029 3.13.0-128-generic #177-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
I used

```
docker-compose run client
```

Comment: What is your host operating system, and what command/arguments are you using with docker-compose?

Comment: @SagarI've updated the question with that info :)

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249744/interactive-shell-using-docker-compose, your command should've worked. The only difference is the command has an extra argument `docker-compose run --rm client`. Have you tried that? I also noticed that you're giving "client" to your docker-compose command. Can you set a name to the container, and try that instead? (not sure it will make a difference, but still)

Comment: Can you post your dockerfile also?

Comment: @Sagar I dont have a seperate docker file. I just pull the image and use "docker-compose run client" to start the container.
Yes I tried that too, But no luck :(

Comment: What version of docker-compose are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If your container does not spawn a long-running process by itself, `docker-compose run` would cause it to run and the exit immediately. Alternatively you could issue a command:

`docker-compose run client sh`

to attach to the open shell session putting you in an interactive mode. If that's not what you're looking for, you need to make sure that the command that you specified (`command: ["/usr/sbin/sshd"]`) is handled correctly by your container. One way of doing it would be to end your entrypoint script with (last line in my entrypoint script):

`exec "$@"`

Following on the above, one reason why your container exists in spite of seemingly correct command being issued (`/usr/sbin/sshd`) is that perhaps your entrypoint overrides / does not keep it running.