# How to run -it with docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`docker run -idt ubuntu:16.04`, after that we can use `docker ps` to see the container starts.

But if use docker compose as next and docker-compose up, we can see `docker ps` cannot find container, from `docker ps -a` we can see it exited.

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  me:
    image: 'ubuntu:16.04'
```

Question: How we could realize `-idt` using docker compose?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The default [CMD of an ubuntu image](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/58cc180042b7ebec2b683576faa00c04d5d011e2/bionic/Dockerfile#L47-L48) is a bash:

```
# overwrite this with 'CMD []' in a dependent Dockerfile
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

From "[Interactive shell using Docker Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150040/6309)", see if adding the lines would help:

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

In docker-compose file we can add `command` label as

```
command: /bin/bash
```

Comment: the post is useful, thanks. But it related to `docker exec -ti <container name> /bin/bash`, any other parameter for `-d` in docker compose? You know, the `docker compose up` not exit now.

Comment: @docke as long as the container does not exit, you can consider it runs in the background. You would need to docker exec anyway to actually use the default bash CMD.

Answer (score 5):

`docker-compose run {image} /bin/bash` it will be already interactive

For docker-compose up, you're not supposed to run it interactively but as a service.

You could alternatively, docker-compose up them, use docker ps to find their image, and then exec into them. This will work if your image is loading a daemon (a server), if your image executes a script and then exits, it will also exit the image, making it impossible to enter it. See this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172605/how-to-get-into-a-docker-container?rq=1) explaining how to do that.

Comment: When use idt, the command will finish at once without let me enter into any interactive bash, but the container still alive. I don't want to exec into any container, just want this container be alive without exit.

Comment: Dockers can't be alive without their processes, you need to have a process running on the background otherwise, docker kills the OS.

Comment: Will container still be alive after doing `docker run -idt ubuntu:16.04`?