# Docker container with console app inserts commands inifitely

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image, docker-entrypoint

I have a Dockerfile that builds an image containing a custom console application:

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

# Some non-relevant steps...

CMD  bin/my-console-app
```

`my-console-app` is a simple console app that, while it runs, it normally gives you the possibility of inserting commands.

For example

```
./my-console-app
my-console> some-command
Some result
my-console> some-other-command
Some other result
```

if I run the container that I've build using the above Dockerfile using `-d`, everything is fine:

`docker run --name my-app --network host -d myapp`

using the network I can see that the console app is correctly running.

However if I run it without `-d`, like:

`docker run --name my-app --network host myapp`

then my terminal will go crazy, like someone is constantly pressing ENTER:

```
my-console> 
my-console> 
my-console> 
my-console> 
my-console> 
my-console> 
my-console> 
my-console>
...
```

and this goes on forever. I cannot insert any command to my console app.

Why is that happening? What should I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by passing `-it` to the `docker run` command.

So now I run my container using:

`docker run --name my-app --network host -it myapp`

**EDIT**: if using docker-compose, to solve this problem specify those 2 options for the service:

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

thanks @user268396

Comment: `docker-compose` is not really meant for this use case. But see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249744/interactive-shell-using-docker-compose