# how to add option in one docker container inside docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sbt-docker-compose

i have several containers in my `docker-compose.yml` before `docker-compose` one of my container run as

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -i imagename:tag
```

i have added this container in my `docker-compose` like this

```
myservice:
   image: imagename:tag
   ports:
     - "8080:8080"
```

now my question is how can i add the `-i` in `docker-compose` i do understand that we can do something like `docker-compose up -i` but i am using [sbt-docker-compose](https://github.com/Tapad/sbt-docker-compose)
for `docker-compose up` -> they provide `dockerComposeUp` but when i try to add 
`dockerComposeUp -i` it ends up with error

```
[error] Expected '-useStaticPorts'
[error] dockerComposeUp -i
[error]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Interactive shell using Docker Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249744/interactive-shell-using-docker-compose)

Comment: thanks for responding but it did not solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

The `-i` is for interactive shell, you can use this usually when you need to connect and interact with the docker container (a good example you would like to execute shell commands inside the docker container) and usually, you don't need this option with docker-compose.

If you would like to connect to the container after creating it, you can use the following command

```
docker exec -it ${container_nsme} sh
```

The error that you get is totally different thing, it seems that the `dockerComposeUp` tool is missing an argument, maybe you can try the following command

```
dockerComposeUp -useStaticPorts
```