# Why does docker-compose up not work interactively?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have this docker-compose file:

```
version: "2"

services: 
    test:
        image: python:3
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true
        container_name: test_c
```

If I just run docker-compose up it doesn't work

```
$ sudo docker-compose up 
Recreating test_c
Attaching to test_c
test_c  | Python 3.8.2 (default, Feb 26 2020, 14:58:38) 
test_c  | [GCC 8.3.0] on linux
test_c  | Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
^CGracefully stopping... (press Ctrl+C again to force)
Stopping test_c ... 
Killing test_c ... done
```

I can work around it by doing:

```
$ sudo docker-compose up -d
$ sudo docker attach test_c
>>>
```

But I want to know why doesn't just work with docker-compose up.

Comment: [_... because logs are being streamed from all the containers._](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36265910/4778343)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that you are spawning an instance of Python and then not providing the command any arguments. Docker containers are essentially [abstractions](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container) around filesystems and resources for single processes from the kernel of the Host OS.

So, in this case, the image you are calling just simply gets created and then calls Python. What happens if you call Python in your shell on your computer? It dumps you into an interactive shell that you can then submit commands to.

Well, that doesn't make much sense. Why call a command that just spins up a shell in a [namespaced](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces) environment that can't communicate with anything else? The real way to use Docker would be to pass arguments to that container image. So that when Docker starts up the Python process, it can pass it an [argument](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html) to do something. For example, run an application that was volume mounted in or copied in via the Dockerfile.

So how do we do that? Well, we can provide your docker-compose file with some Arguments through the [Args](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/) field!

But, to me, it looks like you're just playing around here. So you likely don't have a project to pass to Python with the args field. Or to back into a new Docker Image. What you're likely trying to do is to get into the shell of Python.

The reason that this doesn't automatically happen when Docker runs the `python` command, is because `docker-compose up` or `docker run` doesn't drop you into an interactive environment. It just calls the [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) command in the container. To do that, you have to call an ADDITIONAL command in the container. In this case, a shell. Most container OS come with something like `sh` or `bash` installed on them. I DOUBT that `python` does. However, you can test it using the [exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) command like so:

```
docker-compose up -d
docker exec -it test_c
```

Let me know if you need any additional info or support for this question. Always happy to help you get started with Docker. It's an awesome technology!

Comment: Thanks, this is a very clear and elaborate answer. My confusion was because I assumed that if I'm not detached, then I'm attached, and if I'm attached then I'm interactive. But I suppose attached just means that I see the output.

Comment: And why with other images I can't do it, I just asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66638731/why-do-i-need-tty-true-in-docker-compose-yml-and-other-images-do-not

Answer (score 4):

`docker-compose` was built as orchestration tool for long-running services. Therefor `docker-compose up` is not intended to be used for interactive services and does not allocate a tty or attach stdin to them by default.

To run a service interactively use [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) e.g.

```sh
docker-compose run test
```

which will by default allocate a tty and attach to stdin of that service, so you don't need `stdin_open` and `tty` in `docker-compose.yml`.

---

If you want to run your service in the background but it requires interactive input to start up I'd suggest to rework that service if possible to be able to start non-interactively.