# why do i need tty: true in docker-compose.yml and other images do not?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been looking for the answer for a while, but I haven't found it and I need to understand before I go ahead with my tests.

I am creating an image based on Alpine by installing bash as in the following image:

```
FROM alpine:3.12

RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash rsync gzip \
&& rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*

COPY ./docker/backup/hello.sh /hello.sh

RUN mkdir /backup \
&& chmod u+x /hello.sh

WORKDIR /backup

ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/hello.sh"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

hello.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "=> Hello Word"
echo "$@"
exec "$@"
```

The first time I tried bash I could not access with the following command:

```
docker-compose exec myalpine bash
```

But searching if I found the answer, I had to put in my docker-compose.yml `tty: true`, and I already was able to access the `myalpine` container shell after launching the command `docker-compose up -d`

Resulting in a part of my docker-compose.yml as follows

```
services:
  myalpine:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/backup/Dockerfile
      args:
        - DOCKER_ENV=${DOCKER_ENV}
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-files
    volumes:
      - appdata:/app
      - ./data/app/backup:/backup
  mysql:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./docker/mysql/Dockerfile
      args:
        - MYSQL_VERSION=${MYSQL_VERSION}
        - DOCKER_ENV=${DOCKER_ENV}
    restart: always
    container_name: ${PROJECT_NAME}-mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - db
```

And now my question is why in other services of my docker-compose like `mysql`, I can access the bash without adding `tty:true`?

Example:

```
docker-compose exec mysql bash
```

I can access without having added `tty:true` to the docker-compose.yml, so there must be something in Alpine's image that I don't understand and would like to understand.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had reproduced your example with a cut-down version of the dockerfile and the docker-compose.yaml, and after running `docker-compose up`. First I ran without a `tty` attached, so I have the following:

```
~$ docker-compose up
...
...
WARNING: Image for service myalpine was built because it did not already exist. To rebuild this image you must use `docker-compose build` or `docker-compose up --build`.
Creating test-fies ... done
Attaching to test-fies
test-fies   | => Hello Word
test-fies   | /bin/bash

~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                                  PORTS                                              NAMES
9a72817b0e28   tty_up_myalpine   "sh /hello.sh /bin/b…"   5 minutes ago   Restarting (0) Less than a second ago                                                      myalpine-fies
```

As you can see, the container is restarting all the time. Reason for this is that the `hello.sh` as an entrypoint will receive the command `/bin/bash` and will execute the bash. This will try to create an `interactive shell` but since there is no `tty` the creation of the shell fails and the container is stopped. Because the container is marked `restart: unless-stopped` it will be in a constant loop of restarting.

Since the container is not running, you are not able to execute `docker-compose exec myalpine bash`

Once you add a `tty` to the container, `bash` will be able to create interactive session and the container will be started.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS         PORTS                                              NAMES
745f5139f510   tty_up_myalpine   "sh /hello.sh /bin/b…"   10 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds                                                      myalpine-fies
```

Reason why this is not a case with `mysql` is that this image ends up initiating a `daemon` process which is a non-interactive process that is detached from a `tty`.

Comment: Perfect, one more thing; is there any way to simulate a daemon to not add tty? I think that way the doubt will be clearer.

Comment: daemons are usually written in compiled languages like `C/C++`, but for a proof of concept, you can simulate one by changing the dockerfile's `CMD` line to `CMD ["/bin/bash","-c", "trap \"\" INT; while [ true ]; do sleep 1; done;"]`

Comment: @jcarlosweb I had success with using `bash -i` as the last command of my entrypoint script (or `command`), then I can do `docker-compose run <service-name>` and get a shell in the container.  (doesn't even require `bash` at the end of the run command, nor setting the `tty:` or `stdin_open:` to `true` ... (When troubleshooting/working in a container/service that's not running a daemon, for whatever reason)