# can't run react app with docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, create-react-app

I have a react-app, which simple showing hello-world message but I like to run the app throug docker-container but having this problem. After this message, process stopped without running app..

```
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.17.0.2/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
 Starting the development server...
```

Can't understand what I should do because I have very small app with basic code in Dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine
RUN mkdir /app
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Do I need to install webpack-dev-server, I tried but got version error like 'manually added server' has lower version than already server. so I re-install the webpack-dev-server.

I have created app with 'create-react-app', so I think every dependency is managed automatically..
Is anyone have idea, how can I solve the problem.. thanks in advance (BTW..)

Command which I use to build: `docker build . -t lucki`

Command to run image:  `docker run -p 3000:3000 lucki`

this is project stracture: [image]

after adding DEBUG=* in Dockerfile, I have response as:
[image]

Comment: Can you also add the docker command you are using to bring up the container?

Comment: From inside the container can you verify if the port 3000 is being used? If not, I would recommend checking the default port on which the app is coming up (though if created from create-react-app, the default is 3000 but I don't see it getting logged) and mapping that in docker run command.

Comment: Port 3000 is not being used, and there is no any running container.. there is a stopped container with name 'Luki', but when I tried to run, it shows above message..

Comment: When you say "process stopped", you mean that `docker run` exits and returns to the command line?

Comment: I tried the same for a new react app quickly and things worked as expected. Can you share the logs of the exited lucki container? Command: `docker logs lucki`

Comment: @akazuko I believe the logs are at the top of the question

Comment: Error: No such container: lucki,,,,,,, I got this response.. when I run command 'docker logs lucki'..... actually there is no any running container names 'Lucki'

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem is that the dev mode will not run if it is not an interactive terminal.

Change your docker command to include an interactive terminal:

Add **`-it`** to your `docker run` command (`-i` interactive, `-t` pseudo-TTY) e.g. `docker run -it -p 3000:3000 your_container`

## Canonical troubleshooting

#### Make sure the code runs without docker

Does `npm start` work on the command line?

#### Showing debug info

Add `DEBUG=*` as an environment variable inside your container.`DEBUG` is an environment variable which controls logging for many Node modules.

In your `Dockerfile`, add

```
ENV DEBUG=*
```

Or on the command line, add `-e 'DEBUG=*'` to your `docker` command.

This may help spot error messages which are somehow getting swallowed

#### Run node directly

Instead of running `npm start`, run your file directly.
e.g. in your `Dockerfile`,

```
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

#### Try running another docker container

If this is a problem with your docker setup, running a known good container may help you discover it.

```
docker run --rm -it node:alpine
```

## Improvements

Your `Dockerfile` could also be simplified a bit.

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --production
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

- `mkdir` is not needed, as `WORKDIR` automatically creates the directory.
- `package*.json` will also copy `package-lock.json`
- `--production` will skip installing `devDependencies`
- Putting the `COPY` command last will leverage cache better (you won't have to re-run `npm install` unless your dependencies have changed)

You might also want to use [Tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini). Tini forwards signals, which means `docker stop` and pressing control+c in an interactive terminal will actually stop the node process immediately.

If you are using Docker 1.13+, add `--init` to the command line to have signals forwarded and processes reaped. On older versions, follow the instructions [in the README](https://github.com/krallin/tini#using-tini)

Comment: @akazuko That's correct but I figured it could help and was too big to put in comments

Comment: I edit the question with a new  picture, which I can see after adding DEBUG=* in Dockerfile.. is it helpful..

Comment: @Mr.Learner I have been able to reproduce your problem and I gave the solution in first line of answer

Comment: for those who want to do the same with docker-compose: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150040/2215109

Comment: Nice find @FernandoTholl

Comment: 4 bullet points were very helpful. Thanks @Codebling

Comment: Helped so much!

Answer (score 3):

**Same Problem I have Faced and it's fixed By using the following Command**

**Cause of Problem:-** *Due to react project setup it requires an input trigger to start the server if not it will automatically stop*

**FIX:-** *add `-it` with the `docker run` command*

**Example:-** `docker run --name main-app -it -p 3000:3000 main-image-react`

Comment: I missed to add it in the example sorry for that, I corrected it now

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was running react app in 127.0.0.1 inside the container. When I changed 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 (allows you to access the app from outside of container) it worked. To see if you have the same problem:

1. `sudo docker exec -it <your-container-name> sh`
2. `netstat -tuln`

The result should look like this:

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5173            0.0.0.0:*             LISTEN`

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue
it solved when I use like

```
docker run -it -p 3000:80 <image name>
```

using `-it` other than `-p` and `-d` solved the issue.