# Docker Compose attach one service to stdin and stdout

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Something I'm trying to do is create a docker-compose application that has a single service act as a REPL that can interact with the rest of the services. I tried a variety of ways to get only this service attached to stdin and stdout but I haven't found anything elegant that worked. [This stackoverflow post's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150040/13456640) said `stdin_open: true` and `tty: true` would work and here's what I made with it:

```
version: '3'
services:

  redis:
    image: redis

  python:
    image: python
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Running `docker-compose up` still sends a log of both services and `docker-compose up -d` detaches both of the services. For this example is there an elegant way to get an interactive shell to the python service while only running `docker-compose up ...` (i.e. not running `docker exec`, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

You can [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) an alternate command using the `image:` and other settings in a Docker Compose YAML file.  If that service `depends_on:` other services, it will start them.  The one thing to be aware of is that it will not by default publish the declared `ports:`.

```
docker-compose run python /bin/sh
```

(The Docker setup tends to be a little more optimized around long-running network server processes, like the Redis installation here, and less for "commands" that rely on their stdin for input.  Consider [packaging your application into an image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/), but generally using host tools for learning a language and day-to-day development.  For Python in particular, a [virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#creating-virtual-environments) gives a self-contained playground where you can install packages, as your user account, without interfering with the system Python.)