# Why does a container running a console app simply exits after starting

Tags: docker, .net-core, docker-compose

I want to run a simple dotnet core console app in a container interactively. I am not able to do that and the container simply starts and then exits immediately without fully running the program.

All that the console app has is the followng three statements.

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
var readText = Console.ReadLine(); // Wait for me to enter some text
Console.WriteLine(readText);
```

The last two lines make it interactive.

When I run the container, it prints the Hello World! But then it immediately exits, without waiting for me enter some text. Why? what am I missing?

I was able to run a dotnet core web app in the container in a similar manner, and I am able to map the ports outside and within the container to successfully browse the web app. But when it comes to console app, I am stumped.

I guess there could be something very simple that I am missing. Driving me nuts

The steps to reproduce as described below.

1. Launch Vs2019 and create a new .net core console project.

[image: New DotNet Core Console Project Creation]

2. Add a couple of statements to make it interactive.

[image: Simple DotNet Core Console App]

3. Add Docker support to the created project. Right click the project, Add -> select Container Orchestrator Support

[image: Adding Docker Support To Console App]

[image: Adding Container Orchestrator Support With Docker Compose.jpg]

[image: Docker Linux Containers]

4. Now visual studio creates a set of files and changes the csproj file as well.

[image: Solution Folder In Windows Explorer]

[image: Project Folder In Windows Explorer]

[image: Solution Explorer After Adding Docker Support]

5. In a powershell navigate to folder having the solution file. Run the command "docker-compose up"

[image: Docker-Compose Command InPowerShell]

6. Once the images are built, and containers are up and running, we can see start to see the problem.

[image: Docker Start Container]

7. We can see here Hello-World!. **But it does not wait for me to type something**. Type docker ps -a and see a container that is exited. When I try to start that using docker start -i or docker start -a, the container starts but exits immediately. What should I do to make the container run so that i can type something for my app running in it read? You can see in the docker desktop as well. Even if I start them(using the start button available with the docker desktop UI against each container), it simply stops again.

[image: Docker Containers In Docker Desktop]

8. I had run web apps in containers. With proper port mapping, a web app running inside of a container can be accessed from outside. I had created a dotnet core web app in similar lines described above, modified the docker-compose file to include port mapping(shown below) and when I do docker-compose up, the app is up and running. But with a console app, the container simply exits.

[image: Docker file With Port Mapping For WebApp]

Comment: does this answer your question? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249744/interactive-shell-using-docker-compose

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, you don't have an interactive TTY when the container is started with `docker-compose up`.

You need to add that to your service:

```
stdin_open: true
tty: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I found, Docker compose **run** is an alternative to up command.

```
docker-compose run <service name from docker-compose.yml file>
```

Specifically, for my application, the docker compose file looks as follows.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  dokconsoleapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}dokconsoleapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DokConsoleApp/Dockerfile
#    stdin_open: true
#    tty: true
```

Note the last two lines are commented out.

Now if I run

```
docker-compose run dokconsoleapp
```

The container runs till the end of the program, interactively waiting for me to type an input after Hello-World!.

So statements

```
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

are not needed when you use **run** with docker-compose instead of **up**