# Setting up Rails console on Docker container not taking any input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I was trying to setup Rails console in my dockerized container. The entire application has multiple components and I have set up the orchestration using `docker-compose`. Here is the relevant service from my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
app:
    image: <image_name>
    # mount the current directory (on the host) to /usr/src/app on the container, any changes in either would be reflected in both the host and the container
    tty: true
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
    # expose application on localhost:36081
    ports:
    - "36081:36081"
    # application restarts if stops for any reason - required for the container to restart when the application fails to start due to the database containers not being ready
    restart: always
    depends_on:
    - other-db
    # the environment variables are used in docker/config/env_config.rb to connect to different database containers
    container_name: application
    environment:
    - CONSOLE=$CONSOLE
```

My `Dockerfile` has the following command `ENTRYPOINT /usr/src/app/docker-entrypoint.sh`

And in the `docker-entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "waiting for all db connections to be healthy... Sleeping..."
sleep 1m
mkdir -p /usr/src/app/tmp/pids/
mkdir -p /usr/src/app/tmp/sockets/
if [ "$CONSOLE" = "Y" ];
then
    echo "Starting Padrino console"
    bundle exec padrino console
fi
```

When I run

```
export CONSOLE=Y
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d && docker attach application
```

The console starts up and I see `>>` but I cannot type in it. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150040/8704316) post, I figured that I was missing `stdin_open: true` in the `docker-compose.yml`. Adding it worked like a breeze.

Answer (score 2):

Try starting your container with `-i` mode.

-i, --interactive Attach container's STDIN

something like

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -i && docker attach application`

you can also mix `-d` and `-i` as per need.

Comment: Thanks for this, unfortunately `-i` is a Docker option and not available in the list of options for `docker-compose`. I searched for the corresponding option in docker-compose (for interactive) and this is what I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150040/8704316. Thanks for the direction :)

Comment: glad to heard that you found corresponding option.