# Docker-compose up with input argumen

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to dockers world. I tried to put my script inside docker, my script takes input argument if running directly in a command prompt -- there are two variables inside my scripts that using `input("enter the input here")` argument.

When I tried my scripts directly via cmd `python scripts.py` it runs well, but I tried to dockerize my script using docker-compose but it raised

```
bigquery_1  | Enter input: Traceback (most recent call last):
bigquery_1  |   File "./scripts/bq.py", line 6, in <module>
bigquery_1  |     default_filterDate_1 = (str(input(" Enter input: ")) or `some default arguments`)
bigquery_1  | EOFError: EOF when reading a line
bigquery_1 exited with code 1
```

This is what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./code /usr/src/app/

RUN pip3 install -r ./requirements.txt
```

This is the docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services: 
    bigquery:
        build: ./
        command: python ./scripts/bq.py
```

Is there any workaround on how to pass input variables using docker?

Comment: Your best bet is to use `configparser` and bind a volume to your image, containing your cfg

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't follow @crissal

Comment: Another straightforward approach would be to set `environment:` variables in the `docker-compose.yml` file, which you can read back via `os.environ` in the Python script.  The linked question describes the various ways to run a container via Compose and which ones will actually accept interactive input, if you really can't avoid it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150040/13731995. Basically you need to add `tty` and `stdin_open` to your docker compose file.

```
version: '3.8'

services: 
    bigquery:
        build: ./
        tty: true
        stdin_open: true
        command: python ./scripts/bq.py
```

Comment: I rebuild my docker-compose as you suggested, now I'm stuck at

`
`Starting bigquery_1 ... done`
`Attaching to bigquery_1`
`

Comment: How are you running the container? Something like `docker-compose run bigquery`? If you are using `docker-compose up` maybe try running in detached mode with the `-d` flag?

Comment: Yes, I was using `docker-compose up`. I tried using `docker-compose run bigquery` and now it works like a charm!

Thank you so much, man!