# Error trying run react Docker image on k8s

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, kubernetes, skaffold

I'm building a Micro-services E-commerce project, I need to create a docker image for each server in my project and run them inside K8s cluster. After successfully creating images for all back-end server I tried creating a docker image for my React front-end app, every time I try creating the image this error happened.

Here is my docker configuration:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR /src
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
COPY . .
CMD ["npm ","start"];
```

Here is the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/src/npm '
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Sometimes it throws an error like this:

```
webpack output is served from content not from webpack is served from content not from webpack is served from /app/public docker
```

Comment: There is an extra space inside the quotes in `"npm "`.

Comment: Hello @ImranAbdalla. Was that extra space the case here?

Comment: The extra space solved half of the problem but the image didn't work, the next error is still there.

Comment: Hello @ImranAbdalla. Could you tell us which version of react-scripts are you using?

Comment: I'm using  react-scripts"@3.4.3

Comment: I've made some research and found two possible solutions: 1. Add `stdin_open: true` to your docker-compose. 2. Downgrade your `react-scripts` to v3.4.0. Please try them in that order and let me know about the results.

Comment: The server ran, I added stdin: true to my k8s deployment config and downgraded my react-scripts, but I can't not access it on my browser.

Comment: Hello @ImranAbdalla. One note: you need to add `stdin_open: true` to your docker-compose file, not your deployment. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150040/11560878) as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

To resolve described issues, steps below need to be done.

1. Upgrade Dockerfile:

   ```
   WORKDIR /src
   COPY package*.json ./
   RUN npm install --silent
   COPY . .
   CMD ["npm","start"];
   ```
2. Use version 3.4.0 for `react-scripts`
3. Add `stdin_open: true` to docker-compose file