# Unable to exit Python script in docker with a while True and run with -u option

Tags: python-3.x, docker, python-asyncio, python-3.8

File: Dockerfile

```
From ubuntu:focal-20211006
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install python3 python3-pip

RUN pip install asyncio
RUN pip install apscheduler==3.7.0

COPY test.py /home/testing/test.py
WORKDIR /home/testing

CMD python3 -u ./test.py
```

File:test.py

```
import asyncio
async def main():
    print('Comes to main')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print('Comes to Main 1')
        asyncio.ensure_future(main())
        print('Comes to Main 2')
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        print('Comes to interrupt')
        raise
```

Commands:

```
sudo docker build -t test:test
sudo docker run test:test
```

**Unable to exit the process with ctrl+c on ubuntu:20.04**

Any help would be appreciated

Note: If i use the CMD in Dockerfile to `CMD python3 ./test.py` (without -u option) then there are no outputs. And using docker with docker-compose fails to attach

Comment: run your docker as `sudo docker run -it test:test`.

Comment: @PavelHamerník wow!!.. naice.. can you please post this as answer.. So that I can accept it

Comment: You could try to setup it like in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150040/17726897 . I don't have experience with TTY stuff and compose. If I need to somehow change a running docker I use `docker-compose exec -it service_name /bin/bash` and modify the docker from the inside.

Comment: But often better is to just recreate the container with new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run your docker in interactive tty mode so the shell connects to the docker.

`sudo docker run -it test:test`