# Docker Run Options in a Docker Compose File?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have what is prob a Docker Compose 101 question.  I can spin up a simple Docker container with `docker run`:

```
me@host1:~/dc$
me@host1:~/dc$ sudo docker run -dit --name myContainer 54c9d81cbb44
60d254728f0a763bdda3078bd1c708176ca21e3eced475cb7e2c3edc7859a12c
me@host1:~/dc$
me@host1:~/dc$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND   CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
60d254728f0a   54c9d81cbb44   "bash"    2 minutes ago   Up 2 minutes             myContainer
me@host1:~/dc$
```

Easy!  So then, I translate the above into a `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```
version: "2"
services:
   myService:
      container_name: myContainer2
      image: 54c9d81cbb44
```

When I run the above file, the container exits immediately:

```
me@host1:~/dockerCompose$
me@host1:~/dockerCompose$ sudo docker-compose up
Creating myContainer2 ...
Creating myContainer2 ... done
Attaching to myContainer2
myContainer2 exited with code 0
me@host1:~/dockerCompose$
me@host1:~/dockerCompose$
me@host1:~/dockerCompose$ sudo docker ps  --all
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND   CREATED          STATUS                      PORTS     NAMES
110f648fadbe   54c9d81cbb44   "bash"    14 seconds ago   Exited (0) 13 seconds ago             myContainer2
60d254728f0a   54c9d81cbb44   "bash"    6 minutes ago    Up 6 minutes                          myContainer
me@host1:~/dockerCompose$
```

(The above happens even when I try to spin up myContainer2 without myContainer running.)

So what gives?  I'm tempted to say the docker run "`-dit`" options are what are making the difference here; that is the only difference I see between the `docker run` and `docker-compose` versions.  I've been Googling for "*How to set docker run options in docker-compose file*" for an hour, but pulling up information that isn't applicable here.  I'm clearly missing something fundamental.  Anyone see what?  Thank you.

Comment: I'd probably set the `CMD` in your Dockerfile to run the actual program packaged into the image, rather than an interactive shell.  Does [Interactive shell using Docker Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249744/interactive-shell-using-docker-compose) have the answer to your immediate question?

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks David, the CMD option didn't work for me, but perhaps I didn't use the correct syntax.  I'll look into the shell option.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `stdin_open` and `tty` to true, it'll stay up. Those are equivalent to the `i` and `t` options.

```
version: "2"
services:
   myService:
      container_name: myContainer2
      image: 54c9d81cbb44
      stdin_open: true
      tty: true
```

Start the container with `docker-compose up -d` to run it detached.

Comment: Yes, that did it!  Thank you, I wouldn't have found this otherwise.  :)