# Docker - Container Bash not responding after running docker-compose up -d

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

If I build from the Dockerfile I can run the `docker run IMAGE_ID /bin/bash` and browse the container.

But if I run `docker-compose up -d from docker-compose.yml` and run `docker attach`, it doesn't respond, it stays still in the container terminal and sometimes leaves the container terminal alone

Follow my docker files

`Dockerfile`

```docker
FROM nginx:1.21.6
    
EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /etc/nginx

ENTRYPOINT /bin/bash
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  reverse:  
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./nginx/docker 
    image: reverse/nginx
    container_name: reverse
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443  
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx
    tty: true
```

Comment: Why did you change `ENTRYPOINT` for `nginx` image? Run `docker ps -a` to see if it's running or exited. Also change `build:` to `build: .` and add a `dot` after that.

Comment: Try `docker-compose run service` instead of `docker-compose up`. `docker-compose up` doesn't work for me even though I specified `stdin_open: true`.
See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36265910/11964524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to provide interactive input after attaching you also need to set [`stdin_open: true`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir) in the `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  reverse:
    # ...
    tty: true 
    stdin_open: true
```

But depending on what you want to achieve with this probably a better solution would be

- [`docker-compose exec reverse /bin/bash`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/exec/) or
- [`docker-compose run reverse /bin/bash`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/).