Docker run -> Docker compose
I am runnig postgressql in a docker container.
I have succesfully run the following using docker run:
docker run -it --rm --name postgres-master \
--net postgres \
-e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Password1234!\
-e POSTGRES_DB=postgres \
-e PGDATA="/data" \
-v ./pgdata:/data \
-v ./config:/config \
-v ./archive:/mnt/server/archive \
-p 5000:5432 \
postgres:15.0 -c 'config_file=/config/postgresql.conf'

And then if I run I get the postgres prompt:
postgres -d postgres -U postgres

I then moved it to docker-compose.yaml and I get the following:
version: 3.1

services:
    postgres:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  container_name: postgres-master
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER="postgres"
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD="Password1234!"
            - POSTGRES_DB="postgres"
            - PGDATA="/data"
        volumes:
            - ./pgdata:/data
            - ./config:/config
            - ./archive:/mnt/server/archive
        ports:
            - 5000:5432
        image: postgres:15.0 
        command: -c 'config_file=/config/postgresql.conf'                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        networks:
            - local
networks:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  local:
      name: local

There are 3 dirs created. config, data & archive
Within the config we have page_hba.conf, postgresql.conf and pg_ident.conf.
The postgresql.conf:
# -----------------------------
# PostgreSQL configuration file
# -----------------------------
#

data_directory = '/data'
hba_file = '/config/pg_hba.conf'
ident_file = '/config/pg_ident.conf'

port = 5432
listen_addresses = '*'
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 128MB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix
max_wal_size = 1GB
min_wal_size = 80MB
log_timezone = 'Etc/UTC'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'Etc/UTC'

#locale settings
lc_messages = 'en_US.utf8'          # locale for system error message
lc_monetary = 'en_US.utf8'          # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'en_US.utf8'           # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'en_US.utf8'              # locale for time formatting

default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'

#replication
wal_level = replica
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'test ! -f /mnt/server/archive/%f && cp %p /mnt/server/archive/%f'
max_wal_senders = 3

The problem is with getting the psql prompt.  If I try and run the following within the container:
psql -d postgres -U postgres

I get an error:
psql: error: connection to server socket /var/run/postgresql/.s.PSQL.5432" failed: Fatal"


Ive tried many things such as change the command/username, different ports. e.tc.
Do you know where I am going wrong?

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249744/interactive-shell-using-docker-compose

Can you connect with psql from the host?  You shouldn't need debugging tools like docker exec to interact with the database.  The double quotes in the environment: block may also be causing problems; I believe this sets the variable PGDATA to a value "/data" including double quotes as part of the string.
